# Build apk name with variables

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, build

I'm using Eclipse and i have a common problem.

I want put some variable text in the name of my released apk.
When i export my project, eclipse popups a window when i can change the name from the apk, but this is not what i want.

An example:
Project Name: TestApk

I export my apk with my signature and i get a TestApk.apk.

I want to get something like TestkApk+" "+CurrentTime().apk
It could be more complicated, if i would want to get TestkApk+VersionCode.apk
and so for...

There is some solution to get an apk with variables on his name in Eclipse?

Thanks.

PD: I know i can do an script and use Ant to get this, but i would prefer in Eclipse.

Comment: But Eclipse uses Ant to build projects.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know in which file/configuration in eclipse release this task and how to accomplish this task.